# PHP files displayed as text. (Error: module php8.1 does not exits) php 8.1 ubuntu 23

Tags: php, apache, php-8.1

When I want to execute a php file it's displayed as text in my browser.

I tried `sudo a2enmod php8.1` but it shows an error in return that `ERROR: Module php8.1 does not exist!`

Show I tried installing the php module `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php8.1`
but it says
`libapache2-mod-php8.1 is already the newest version (8.1.12-1ubuntu4.3).`

I tried `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php8.1 --reinstall` too.

Comment: what happens when you try to execute php8.1 from the command line: `php8.1 -v`

Answer (score 0):

```
dpkg -L libapache2-mod-php8.1
```

Locate where are the files php8.1.conf, php8.1.load and libphp8.1.so installed by the package.

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available/php8.1.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/php8.1.load
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp8.1.so
```

copy `php8.1.conf` and `php8.1.load` to `/etc/apache2/mods-available/`. If you cannot find `php8.1.load`, you can copy files like `status.load` into `php8.1.load` and put content like this :

```
LoadModule php_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp8.1.so
```

Then, link the `php8.1.load` and `php8.1.conf` into `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/`